# Get username and password from URL in ASP Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, basic-authentication

In my REST API written in C# for Net Core 2.2 I use the Bearer Token Authentication. Now I need to write a single method that accepts Basic Auth. In order to do things simply, i created the method with [AllowAnonymous] then, in the code I check the Authorization header

```
var auth = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
if (!auth.ToLower().StartsWith("basic "))
    return Unauthorized();
```

This works when i make a call from Postman and i set Basic Auth

But when the method is called with username and password in URL the Authorization Header is empty.

How can I get username and password from a URL like this:

```
https://username:password@localhost:7777/api/file/dl2?id=xxxxx
```

Here is my code:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("dl2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadByCryptedIdBasicAuth(string codCat, string id)
{
    var auth = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
    if (!auth.ToLower().StartsWith("basic "))
        return Unauthorized();

    var credentials = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Substring(6)));

    string userName = credentials.Split(':')[0];
    string password = credentials.Split(':')[1];

    // Check username and password
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `method` detais? Additionally `user name` and `password` cannot be pass this way `https://username:password@localhost:7777/api/file/dl2?id=xxxxx`, If you want to pass `userName` and `password` through the `URL` you should do like `https://localhost:7777/api/YourController/method?UserName=UserName&password=password`

Comment: I edited my code. My method is called from another software house that uses the format i writed above. https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters

Comment: Is it completely necessary for you to put credentials in a URL? It's a bad idea

Comment: A comment in the answer you linked to says that this isn't working since 2014. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I don't want to do it! It is the other software house that calls my services this way

Comment: I wrote to the software house that the RCF 3986 specifications no longer allow the use of this syntax and therefore this kind of calls will not be accepted.
Thanks everyone for helping me

Comment: Solved in the sense that we don't support this feature

Comment: Did you tried the way I have commented above? Because the link you have referred is no more working. Let us know your feedback.